# How to set mouse hover for ALL buttons?

Tags: c#, forms, button

I have bunch of buttons on my form. And I would like to make it a bit nicer so button changing color and font to bold when mousei s over it seems like good idea. I would appreciate any help
           `button.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
button.Font = new Font(button.Font.Name, button.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);`

EDIT:
this is working for me:

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.PaleTurquoise;
        ((Button)sender).Font = new Font(((Button)sender).Font.Name, ((Button)sender).Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
    }

    private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
        ((Button)sender).Font = new Font(((Button)sender).Font.Name, ((Button)sender).Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular);
    }
```

(there is button1_mousenter (or mouseleave) set as action for every button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select them all in your Form view and go to the mousehover event.
and write your code like this:

```
private void button_mousehover (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.Cyan;
        ((Button)sender).Font = new Font(((Button)sender).Font.Name, ((Button)sender).Font.Size, ((Button)sender).FontStyle.Bold;
    }
```

Comment: @JaroslavNejedlý sorry it was my bad. I edited the code and now it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you. There is just minor error. Insted ((Button)sender).Bold there is just FontStyle.Bold. It is working now

Comment: @JaroslavNejedlý yeah I just wanted to give u the idea of how it is done, didn't pay attention to that. I edit the post so anyone using it later wont have problem using it. Happy I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add MouseEnter and MouseLeave events to your buttons that changes the buttons' colors.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave(v=vs.110).aspx

```
// bind handler to MouseEnter Event
this.yourButton1.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.allButtons_MouseEnter);

this.yourButton2.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.allButtons_MouseEnter);

// bind handler to MouseLeave Event
this.yourButton1.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.allButtons_MouseLeave);

this.yourButton2.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.allButtons_MouseLeave);

// enter handler
private void allButtons_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
    btn.Font = new Font(btn.Font.Name, btn.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
}

// leave handler
private void allButtons_MouseLeave(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.BackColor = Color.DeepPink; // whatever your original color was
    btn.Font = new Font(btn.Font.Name, btn.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular);
}
```